# How can I convert a Python scipy.optimize.linprog function into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linear-programming, scipy-optimize, glpk

I've been trying to perform a linear optimisation which works in Python in the format
`scipy.optimize.linprog(c,Aub,bub)` but within a Javascript file. The `numeric` library works, however is too outdated to be correctly bundled within vite.

It looks like the `node-glpk` or `lp_solve` libraries would be suitable, but I'm confused as to how to format my code to run using the same input variables as in Python, and the documentation doesn't make sense to my brain at the moment...

c is a 1D coefficient array, Aub is 2D inequality constraint matrix and bub is 1D inequality constraint vector.

Thanks!